# How to get value from admin configuration for my custom module

Tags: module, magento2.4.1

I have created a custom module, and added values directly in my code like hardcode, how to get those values from the admin configuration and passed to my code.

Block:

```
<?php
namespace Zero\Customerreview\Block;

class Customerreview extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
        
     public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,        
        array $data = []
     ) {
       
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
  
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        
    }



    public function getCustomerReview(){    

        $authorization = "Authorization: Bearer nhuhtrbhuithtobtougbtgbigbrigboirubgurbgrbgibniutgtbgbuigbuobtrbntrhtrnijhiotgnbgnbhtrhnitgnbgibnrtshgtrnirtn'jhiotrtsnnioonrtrhtitrh";

        

        $url = 'https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/123456789/locations/987654321/reviews';  

        $ch = curl_init();
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);        
        $allData = json_decode($output, TRUE); // You will get all the data

        return $allData;
    }
}
```

I want to get $authorization and account id ( https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/123456789)  details from admin configuration, and also how to pass that account id in URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Create fields in the admin through system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../Magento/Config/etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="zero" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>Zero - Customerreview</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="customerreview" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Customerreview</label>
            <tab>zero</tab>
            <resource>Magento_Config::config</resource>
            <!-- <resource>VENDOR_MODULE::path_to_the_acl_resource</resource> -->
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>General Configuration</label>                
                <field id="review_auth" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Authorization Token</label>
                    <comment>Enter Authorization Token.</comment>
                </field>
                <field id="review_account_id" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Account Id</label>                    
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

> 2. Get value from the admin configuration

```
<?php
namespace Zero\Customerreview\Block;

class Customerreview extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
     protected $helper;
        
     public function __construct(        
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,     
        array $data = []
     ) {        
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
  
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        
    }
    public function getCustomerReview(){   
            
        //Here you need to check system.xml file and get section_id/group_id/field_id
        $authentication = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('customerreview/general/review_auth', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        $accountId = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('customerreview/general/review_account_id', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

        $authorization = "Authorization:".$authentication;

        

        $url = 'https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/'.$accountId.'/locations/987654321/reviews';  

        $ch = curl_init();
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);        
        $allData = json_decode($output, TRUE); // You will get all the data
        return $allData;
    }
}
```

Comment: can u pls help me with that token issue, i shared the script, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**To get data from admin configurations**

First of all create a directory "Helper" inside `Zero\Customerreview/Helper` and then create a file name `Zero\Customerreview/Helper/Data.php` inside Helper

```
<?php
namespace Zero\Customerreview\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    public function getConfig($config_path)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            $config_path,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
}
```

Now in your block or controller call helper

```
<?php
namespace Zero\Customerreview\Block;

class Customerreview extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
     protected $helper;
        
     public function __construct(
        \Zero\Customerreview\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,        
        array $data = []
     ) {
        $this->helper = $helper;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
  
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        
    }
    public function getCustomerReview(){   
            
        //Here you need to check system.xml file and get system_id/group_id/field_id
        $abc = $this->helper->getConfig('system_id/group_id/field_id');
        //echo $abc;
        return $abc;
    }
}
```

Comment: May i know what is mean system_id/group_id/field_id

Comment: You can check this in your system.xml file from the module you want to get data

Answer (score 1):

@zus system_id/group_id/field_id which is getting from your module system.xml

1. system_id means Section id from your system.xml
2. group_id means group id which is under section tab
3. field_id means field id which is under the group section
   and that thing used for getting system configuration value.